# Redirect website based on Geographical location in Magento store

Tags: php, magento, gis

I have eCommerce store in Magento framework, I want to display store based on geographical location. For example if I am accessing store from India then URL should read like www.website.com.in and if I am accessing website from US then URL should read like www.website.com.us and also at the same time based on URL store will display content. Please suggest.

Comment: Is this task done? What are the steps that u have taken to solve this? Does mamind extension helps ur problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example on how you can show different websites based on location.
http://rosskendall.com/blog/web/using-geoip-with-magento-and-multiple-sites
The main idea is to use a database for IP geolocation. (MaxMind).
The example shows how to load a specific store view depending on the location, but it can be changed to redirect to some url if you have different urls for your websites.

Comment: Does this extension works fine as required or did you try this? because I am not sure on this. But Right now I have the same requirement. So can u suggest me on this?

Comment: @Johngrews. I didn't test it. I just found nice words about it on the web. Also it uses the MaxMind database that is being used by a lot of people (outside Magento).